# css transition not working as expected with JavaScript add class

Tags: javascript, html, sass, css-transitions

I am trying to create a transition effect using css and the JavaScript `classList.add` function. My expected behaviour is that when the button is clicked, a grey background appears and on top of that another element slides in from the right. At the moment everything appears as expected, but for some reason the slide transition doesn't happen. Any ideas? I have created a basic version of my code below:

html:

```
<button id="product-form__book-product">Add</button>

<div class="product-form-slider" id="product-form-slider">
  <div class="product-form-slider__inner" id="product-form-slider__inner">
    <span class="close" id="product-form-slider__close-button">&times;</span>
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.product-form-slider {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  right: -65%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  right: 0;
  &.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.product-form-slider__inner {
  right: -65%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #545151;
  position: absolute;
  &.slide-in {
    right: 0;
    transition: right 1s linear;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var productFormBookButton = document.getElementById('product-form__book-product');
var productFormSlider = document.getElementById('product-form-slider');
var productFormSliderInner = document.getElementById('product-form-slider__inner');
var productFormSliderCloseButton = document.getElementById('product-form-slider__close-button');

productFormBookButton && productFormBookButton.addEventListener('click', showFormSlider);

function showFormSlider() {
  productFormSlider.classList.add('active');
  productFormSliderInner.classList.add('slide-in');
}

// Close slider on click of close button
productFormSliderCloseButton && (productFormSliderCloseButton.onclick = function() {
  productFormSliderInner.classList.remove('slide-in');
  productFormSlider.classList.remove('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by setting a 2 millisecond `timeout` function on my transition. This way I forced the transition to happen after the show of the background.

```
function showFormSlider() {
  productFormSlider.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function(){ productFormSliderInner.classList.add('slide-in') }, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `transition` property to main classes.

```
.product-form-slider {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  right: -65%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  right: 0;
  &.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.product-form-slider__inner {
  right: -65%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #545151;
  position: absolute;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  &.slide-in {
      right: 0;
  }
}
```

Also if you want animate properties like `display` not working very well. If you want to show and hide elements with the transition, you should use `opacity`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This still doesn't seem to work. I get the same result.